# How to add products in Magento 1.7 using php scripts outside magento structure

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I need to import products from "POS Winward" software to my magento store.After going through Import/Export products modules including MAGMI,Custom IMPORT/EXPORT i am unable to fulfill my purpose.

First of all is it feasible?
If Yes,Can you tell me about the product data tables,images data tables,category data tables needed to update while importing products using CSV or XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POS Winward exports data in the XML format.
Use an XML Parser and generate a csv as Magento acceptable format.
MAGMI imports csv file to impoprt product.

Exactly, MAGMI itself a powerful tool for import Product Purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I think you didn't investigate magmi enough.

- Through datapump API, magmi can use PHP arrays as input for ingest , so you're free to fill them the way you want.
- Magmi also has SQL Datasource to have input handled by a SQL request on a database
- Of course, you could also use CSV to import

Then this is more a question of knowing how POS Winward data is accessible and then to fill up the good columns of your source in order to be compatible with magmi importable columns and also (and not the easiest part) , a way to match the product datamodel of your magento instance (since notions like product type configurable/simples/grouped and all needed attributes as well as necessary associations) may not exist in the POS Winward datamodel.

In that latter case, you need to define "semantical mapping" rules and apply them to convert one "Winward POS product" into a "Magento product"

There is no magic bullet, but magmi might be the right gun ;)

Comment: hi @dweeves..click here **[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145507/magmi-bundled-products-and-re-indexing-issue)**..i hope you can answer this as well as i am supposing, you are the one who wrote script for Magmi..

Comment: @dweeves do you know if its possible to request information on a database directly to magento, not using SQL Datasource provided on the magmi UI. I tried several times with different approaches but i cannot make it work with sql. i create a question with further details -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130191/magmi-generic-sql-datasource-1-0-2-usage , brgds!