# Magmi Bundled Products and Re-indexing issue in Magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magmi

I am using Magento 1.7x version.I need to create a script to import products.I used Magmi as an Import Product Tool which helps me to

1. import Simple ,Grouped and Configurable Products not bundle products
2. create a script to run a cron job to automate the process.

**Problem**: My products are not showing on front end whereas these are visible on backend.I studied somewhere and i find its about re-indexing the database tables.

**Questions**:
1. How to rebuild index (script is cron job)after running a Magmi import process because i am unable to rebuild index using:
=>On the fly indexer v0.1.5
=>Magmi Magento Reindexer v1.0.2

2.Does Magmi support importing bundled product with custom bundle types?

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a cron job, you could run the magento indexer (which is the program called by magmi for reindexing) , using the following command lines (better put them at the end of the shell script that is ran by cron)

```
cd <yourmagentodir>/shell
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_price
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
php indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
php indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
```

There are other indexes, but both catalog_category_product & catalog_url are handled much more efficiently by on the fly indexer plugin.

Magmi does not support bundled yet.

Comment: hey thanks, it worked.please update if there are any updates about importing bundled products in Magmi.

Comment: Instead of reindexing each individually, you could do `php indexer.php reindexall` which will update all of the indexes.  Granted, there are a couple of indexes not related to the inventory, however I find that their impact of being reindexed each time is negligible. =

Comment: @Axel, In fact, depending on number of items, URL reindexing may be hours long that's why i took care of it with on the fly indexer and did not advise to use reindexall. Since magmi on the fly indexer also reindexes catalog_category_product ,the  list i advised is not an equivalent to reindexall